# Find latest version in SQL (error when dates match)

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I am trying to find out the oldest version by partion and order by the record/version #. This seems to work however, I encounter a bug where the start date for the latest record is the same (version 11092.0004 and 11092.0003).
How can I make it count the 11092.0004 as the latest record?

```
        SELECT     
                CONVERT(float, (DIM_Record.DWID + (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DIM_Record.DWID ORDER BY DIM_Record.SRC_START_DTTM)*.0001)) - .0001) AS [Version ID]
            ,   CONVERT(bit, CASE WHEN LAG(DIM_Record.SRC_START_DTTM) OVER (PARTITION BY DIM_Record.DWID ORDER BY DIM_Record.SRC_START_DTTM DESC) IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Current Record]
            ,    DIM_Record.SRC_START_DTTM as Start_date
        FROM Date_Table.DIM_Record_HISTORY DIM_Record
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Date_Table.DIM_Record_TYP
                ON DIM_Record.DSN = DIM_Record_TYP.DSN
                    AND DIM_Record.PRJ_TYP_DSID = DIM_Record_TYP.DSID
        WHERE DIM_Record.DWID = '11092'
```

I tried to edit my code to add the [Version ID] into my code for [Current Record] like so

```
CONVERT(bit, CASE WHEN LAG(DIM_Record.SRC_START_DTTM) OVER (PARTITION BY DIM_Record.DWID ORDER BY (    CONVERT(float, (DIM_Record.DWID + (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DIM_Record.DWID ORDER BY DIM_Record.SRC_START_DTTM)*.0001)) - .0001)) DESC) IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Current Record]
```

But I get the following Error:

> window functions cannot be used in the context of another window function

My data:

| Version ID | Current Record | Start_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11092.0003 | 1 | 6/2/2022 12:00:00 AM |
| 11092.0004 | 0 | 6/2/2022 12:00:00 AM |
| 11092.0002 | 0 | 1/31/2022 5:36:46 PM |
| 11092.0001 | 0 | 1/31/2022 12:00:00 AM |
| 11092 | 0 | 1/3/2022 4:31:44 PM |

Here VERSION ID: 11092.0004, I want Current record to read 1.

Comment: You could use a sub-query to calculate the `LAG` first, and use that in the `ROW_NUMBER`. I would wonder, though, if that data doesn't require cleansing

Comment: would a temporal table solve this for you?

Comment: The sample data doesn't match your query, so we can't run this. I'm guessing you don't actually need to nest them here, you can just use `LAG(DIM_Record.SRC_START_DTTM) OVER (PARTITION BY DIM_Record.DWID ORDER BY DIM_Record.SRC_START_DTTM DESC)` for the same effect

Comment: @Charlieface I used `LAG(DIM_Record.SRC_START_DTTM) OVER (PARTITION BY DIM_Record.DWID ORDER BY DIM_Record.SRC_START_DTTM DESC) ` and that resulted in 11092.0003 returning null for its date, how do I do it for 11092.0004?

Comment: Doesn't sound like that is what should happen. Like I said, I haven't got proper sample data to be able to run your query

Answer (score 0):

use `ROW_NUMBER()` = `COUNT(*)` to determine if it is the last running number in the series

```
CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DIM_Record.DWID 
                                 ORDER BY DIM_Record.SRC_START_DTTM)
        = COUNT(*)     OVER (PARTITION BY DIM_Record.DWID)
     THEN 1
     ELSE 0
     END
```